# Using Google Map & Street View in JavaFX

Tags: java, google-maps, javafx, javafx-8

I've tried to use WebView and JxBrowser, and they both work absolutely fine for google maps but street view doesn't support it anymore. IIRC it's because WebView doesn't support it's new JS code. ([Problem looks like this if you were wondering](https://i.gyazo.com/773738b5bf968159933d635dd75839d1.png)).

If I have to I'll use the google API but last I've heard is that it's not supported well anymore and I need to manipulate the URL so using a browser is preferable. Does anyone know any fixes or alternatives? Any help is appreciated

Comment: This is true for WebView but does it also apply to JxBrowser? The Chromium backend should be able to handle street view.

Comment: @mipa I tried JxBrowser a few weeks ago and had the same problem, I might have another try in a bit if I need to but it requires to buy it so ideally I'd rather not use it

Answer (score 0):

There is an advanced library for working with Google Maps that is developed with pure Java API. Personally I have not tried it for StreetView.

The Library can be found [here](http://rterp.github.io/GMapsFX/).
The issue that you have reported is already open [here](https://github.com/rterp/GMapsFX/issues/146).

Comment: The lib is no longer maintained